# How to use two `with` in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I try to show two flash messages in Laravel using `with`:

```
return redirect('cabinet/result')->with('user', $client->unique_code)->with('fio', $client->name.' '.$client->secondname. ' '.$client->patronymic);
```

Then I display this as:

```
{{ session('fio') }}  {{ session('unique_code') }}
```

It shows me nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, when you pass data with the method 'with' to a view, it does not get stored in the session, it is just made available as a variable with the same name to the view that gets loaded after the redirect takes place.

You have two options:

#### Passing an array of key value pairs to the view

You may pass an array of data to views:

```php
return view('greetings', ['name' => 'Victoria', 'last_name' => 'Queen']);
```

As you can see by the way the method is implemented in {root}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php

```php
/**
 * Add a piece of data to the view.
 *
 * @param  string|array  $key
 * @param  mixed   $value
 * @return $this
 */
public function with($key, $value = null)
{
    if (is_array($key)) {
        $this->data = array_merge($this->data, $key);
    } else {
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

the method accepts either a key value pair, or an array. All the keys of this array will be available in the view that is loaded next as php variables with the same name (of course you need to append the dollar sign to the calls in the view). So in the 'greetings' view you would retrieve them as such:

```php
$variable1 = {{ $name }}

$variable2 = {{ $last_name }}
```

#### Flashing an array of key value pairs to the next session

You can do pretty much the same using the flashInput method that is found in {root}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php:

```php
/**
 * Flash a key / value pair to the session.
 *
 * @param  string  $key
 * @param  mixed   $value
 * @return void
 */
public function flash($key, $value)
{
    $this->put($key, $value);

    $this->push('_flash.new', $key);

    $this->removeFromOldFlashData([$key]);
}
```

You would do that as such:

```php
$request->session()->flashInput('flashData' => ['key1' => value1, 'key2' => value2]);
```

The difference here is that the data would not be available as variables to your loaded view. Instead they would be stored in an associative array in the session and you would retrieve the stored values this way:

```php
$variable1 = {{ session('flashData['key1']) }}
```

```php
$variable2 = {{ session('flashData['key2']) }}
```

*Resources*

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session

If you feel that this solved your problem please mark the answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

First make sure your queries return data. 

In my projects, I use simple way for doing it.

```
$user = $client->unique_code; //now user has the code
$fio = $client->name.' '.$client->secondname. ' '.$client->patronymic;
//please make sure this returns your indented result.

return redirect('cabinet/result')->with('user', $user)->with('fio',$fio );
```

I hope this will work,

Comment: this is how I m returning values from controller to view. I modified you code for that.did you try this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$user = 'user';
$fio = 'fio';

return redirect('cabinet/result')
           ->with('user', $user)
           ->with('fio', $fio);
```

For View:

```
{{ Session::get('user') }} {{ Session::get('fio') }}
```